# Removing data from array correctly

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing the problem that I fill up an array with data and when I want to remove it later, even though I call the `removeAll()` the array still is not empty.

Better see my code for a more clear view on the problem

**Updated new code**

```
  @objc func textFieldDidChange() {

    doSearch()

    if let commentText = commentTextField.text , !commentText.isEmpty {
        sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)
        sendButton.isEnabled = true
        return
    }

    sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: UIControlState.normal)
    sendButton.isEnabled = false
}


func doSearch() {
    let caption = commentTextField.text

    let words = caption?.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    self.usersSuggestion.removeAll()


    for var word in words! {
        self.usersSuggestion.removeAll()


        if word.hasPrefix("@") {
            word = word.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters)
            self.isCellSelected = true
            self.usersSuggestion.removeAll()
            API.User.suggestUsers(withText: word, completion: { (user) in
            print("closure", word)


                self.usersSuggestion.append(user)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                print("@", self.usersSuggestion.count)

            })

            self.usersSuggestion.removeAll()
            tableView.reloadData()


        } else {
            self.isCellSelected = false
            self.usersSuggestion.removeAll()
            tableView.reloadData()

        }
        self.usersSuggestion.removeAll()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }



}
```

I am facing the problem here that the array, even though I call multiple times the removeAll() method, never gets back to 0. When I have 2 user, link one, the next time I write an @ I get the 2 users+ the linked user (so him twice). I can do it infinitely, having like 100 userSuggestions with just 2 existing users.

photos

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the type of `userSuggestions`?

Comment: var usersSuggestion : [UserModel] = [].  Starts off as an empty array, gets filled up within my doSearch() functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the count immediately after inserting an element in the array.  This will alway give a count of 1.

```
                                       // count was zero
self.hashTags.insert(hashTag, at: 0)   // adding one
print("# = ", self.hashTags.count)     // count is now 1
```

Given that the API.user... function uses a completion handler, I would assume that this happens in a separate thread or at least asynchronously so you could event get into situations where the UI shows empty and suddenly shows one.

You may want to structure your code differently to better convey the separation between requesting data and displaying the (asynchronously obtained) results.   Embedded completion handlers tend be misleading and give the impression that execution will happen in their visually organized sequence.

Comment: My problem is that I tested it with the usersSuggestion block and it does work fine. When I write a @ ( I am building the Instagram feature of linking hashtags) I can link users without problems, when I link via # I can properly link hashtags, but if I link again with @ it still shows the data from the hashtags array instead of users array, because the hashtags array is not empty ( it displays the latest used hashtag) I hope that its more clear now

Comment: To be even more specific: The count 1 gets printed out all the time, even though there is no # or @ in front of it. This only happens after I linked one hashtag, but does not after linking users.

Comment: To get back once again to your answer, the print statement even appears by writing whitespace, so even when there is no # close by, the count is always 1

Comment: Shouldn't you clear both arrays before  starting the loop on words ?  Right now, if you use @xxx right after using #yyy, the hashTags array will not  be cleared because in the word.hasPrefix("@") block you don't clear hashTags.

Comment: I have tried, can you please recheck my code, I have updated it with the variation of just linking a user and no hashtags, still facing the same problem never be able to empty the array entirely.

Comment: Clearing the array multiple times in the search() function isn't necessary (only the first removeAll() is relevant) and makes the logic a bit confusing.  I noticed you are modifying the search field's content in the row selection event which could produce some strange results if you are also changing the selection while the user makes changes to the search field.  This makes me wonder if there are other places in your code that change the array or the search field.  By the way, code pictures make things harder as we cannot copy/paste the text to experiment.

Comment: I have commented out the entire function which manipulates the text when the cell is clicked, still the same problem. When I write @. @. @ I get each time more and more the same 2 users suggested ( first 2 times, second time 4 times, third time 6 times)

Comment: I think the problem is the for ... in loop, because it will search for every word containing the @ sign. I need a way to remove the used words out of the array and only have the newest one. Any clue?